# WordPress Theme Displaying Incorrectly in IE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on http://chaseonthelake.com/. The site works fine in FireFox, however when opened in Internet Explorer, the transparency of the dropdown doesn't display correctly, making the dropdown unreadable and the sidebar items have black borders around them. Take a look at the image below to see what I am talking about. Any help with these issues would be appreciated! [image]

Comment: Hi you can replace background images into rgba color with opacity more information check this http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: Can you check to see if it works in Internet explorer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the black borders might be arising because of default CSS styles applied by IE to certain elements.  I would recommend using a "CSS reset" like Eric Meyer's before any of your CSS to standardize basic styling across browsers.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

As for the menu transparency, if you're using the `rgba` property in CSS to do transparency, it won't work in IE 8 or below.  You can use a standard `rgb` property as a fallback that gets overridden by the `rgba` property in browsers that support it, like this:

```
.menu{
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) /*Fallback for non-rgba-supporting browsers*/
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: I just added that to my CSS. Can you see how it looks now? I don't have IE available to me right now

Comment: The black borders are still there

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`.class {filter:alpha(opacity=value);}`

for this images in your css. I hope it will work for you and use css

`a img {border:none 0;}`

Comment: I don't see a .class in Style.css?

Comment: The black borders are still there even after a img{border:none 0;}

Comment: find out .home .categories img and .categories img{filter:alpha(opacity=40);} in styles.css and remove that

Comment: Check out the image I posted, the dropdown menus don't display correctly in IE7 and below